# PHP script that will run a shell script from remote computers

Tags: php

I've been searching through out the net on how I can possibly make it happen in php. The scenario is my php application is in computer A and the shell script file that I want to execute is in Computer B. and I want my php application in computer A to execute the shell script file in Computer B.

I understand that permission plays a very important role on this but I can access computer B so no problem for setting permission.

By the way, computer A is windows server and Computer B is kubuntu. Does anyone has an idea? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use ssh functions in PHP to achieve the thing you are looking for,

refer http://php.net/manual/en/ssh2.requirements.php

Answer (score 1):

Too bad can't add packages, just solved it by this

```
public function execScript($connection, $script)
{

    // Execute script        
    exec("ssh $connection $script 2>&1", $output, $error);

    if ($error) {
        throw new Exception ("\nError: ".print_r($output, true));
    }

    return $output;
}
```